Thriller Hiking Movie?
I am trying to find a movie my parents rented around 2006. I think it was set around that time somewhere in the states. 
From what I can remember it starts off with a young couple hiking together when the boyfriend goes to the bathroom but never comes back. His girlfriend tries to find him but he is presumed dead. 
I think a year goes by and she has stopped hiking since her boyfriend disappeared, until a few men arrive in her town looking for a guide. I can't remember how it ends up happening but she decides to take them hiking (I think she was hoping to find the boyfriends body) but these men are actually doing something with satellites? 
This is where my memory gets blurry on the plot and I can't remember much else but I have been trying to track down this film for a while and would really appreciate some help finding it!

Sounds like the 2004 thriller What Lies Above (AKA Snowman's Pass) with Nicole Eggert.

Still struggling to accept her fiance's death in a rock climbing accident, mountain guide DIANA PENNINGTON gratefully accepts industrialist CURT SEAVER's offer to find the body using a new satellite imagery technology his company has developed. But while traversing the legendary "Snowman's Pass" with Curt and his companions HUGO and TYLER, Diana is horrified to discover the search for her fiancé is a decoy; they are in fact hunting for a fallen spy satellite, property of an enemy foreign power.

Her fiance doesn't disappear after going to the bathroom, though. He falls from a rock and his body mysteriously disappears while Diana goes to get help. The film is currently available on Youtube in this link, and here's the trailer:




WOW thank you! never thought I would find out what the movie was haha...doesn't look as great as I remember but I'm so glad I know what it is now :)
